# Div in figcaption which is moved into the figure's image doesn't show its background

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, figure

*Hello everybody,*

**the markup:**

```
<td>
  <figure>
    <img width="351" height="221" src="somesource.jpg" class="someclass" />
  </figure>
  <figcaption>
    <div id='counter'>
        0
    </div>
    <div id='captionbox'>
      <div id='content'>
            Nur Dummy-Content. </br>
            Das ist witzig, denn hier ist eine neue Zeile!
      </div>
     </div>
  </figcaption>
</td>
```

**The css:**

```
#counter {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -50px 5px 5px 305px;
    background: white;
}

figure{
    margin: 0;
}

#primary table td{
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```

**The output:**
http://s14.directupload.net/images/140710/edkfhb5m.png
http://s7.directupload.net/images/140710/ceuceel7.png

**The problem:**

The counter-div, of course, should have a white background. Actually it has a white background but it's hidden behind the figure's image. I'm wondering why the "0" is above the figure's image while the white-background of the counter is behind. 
Do you have any suggestions/solutions/hints? :)

**Thank you** so much people!

**Regards**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements within the same stacking context draw the backgrounds first and then the contents. The white background of the counter is there, it's just behind the image, because the paint order in your example is:

- background of `figure`
- background of `#content`
- content of `figure` (the image)
- content of `#content`

The best solution is probably to give both the `figure` and `#content` (or `figcaption`) a `z-index` and `position: relative` so that the `z-index` can apply.